# Xamarin MasterDetail App Title not displaying text

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am new to Xamarin and been working on using a MasterDetailPage that I want to be used in all my pages with the menu and title. Because of this I was thinking the best way to complete this was to use the app.xaml resources section. I have the color working but I am not getting the text and also need to add png logo image file.

> Is this the best way to complete something like this or is there a better way?

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <Color x:Key="UchBlueColor">#243359</Color>
    </ResourceDictionary>
    <Style TargetType="NavigationPage">
        <Setter Property="BarBackgroundColor" Value="{StaticResource UchBlueColor}"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="BarTextColor" Value="White"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="Title" Value="App Name"></Setter>
    </Style>
</Application.Resources>
```

MainPage.xaml

```
<MasterDetailPage.Detail>
    <NavigationPage>
        <x:Arguments>
            <pages:HomePage />
        </x:Arguments>
    </NavigationPage>
</MasterDetailPage.Detail>
```

homePage.xaml

```
 <ContentPage.Content Padding="0" Title="Browse">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically `Title` is a feature of `ContentPage` and while `NavigationPage` does have this property it is essentially assigned to something else as soon as any `ContentPage` is loaded which is almost the same as always. So probably a good idea is to use the `ContentPage` to define the `Title`.

Comment: I updated the code but I am still not getting the title to display